# Apparent disagreement in curvature drift formulas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, curvature, plasma-physics

Suppose we have some charged particle above the ionosphere. Then in a simplified model, it will experience a curvature and gradient drift. Assume further that a particle is in the equatorial plane. Since the particle is in the equatorial plane, using spherical coordinates, the magnetic field will yield the form:

$$
\vec{B}(r)=B_\theta(r) \hat{\theta}
$$

In many textbooks a formula for the curvature drift comes as:

$$
\vec{v}_c=\frac{2U_{||}}{qB^4}[(\vec{B}\cdot\nabla)\vec{B}]\times\vec{B}
$$

However, by applying this expression I get:

$$
\vec{B}\cdot\nabla=\frac{B_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
$$

$$
(\vec{B}\cdot\nabla)\vec{B}=\frac{B_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial B_\theta (r)}{\partial\theta}=0
$$

Then we have $\vec{v_c}=0$. But there is another definition that states:

$$
\vec{v}_c=\frac{2U_{||}}{qR_c^2}\frac{\vec{R_c}\times \vec{B}}{B^2}
$$

And since $R_c$ is defined as $R_c=\frac{B_\theta}{\frac{dB_\theta}{dr}}$ then $\vec{R_c}$ pointing in the radial direction which will clearly give a non zero drift curvature. I know that the last one is the correct one, but where is the mistake on the first try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gradient drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center) of a particle is given by:
$$
V_{\nabla B} = \frac{ w_{\perp} }{ q_{s} \ B } \ \left[ \frac{ \mathbf{B} \times \nabla B }{ B^{2} } \right] \tag{0}
$$
where $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic field vector, $B$ is its magnitude, $q_{s}$ is the charge (including sign) of the particle species $s$, and $w_{\perp}$ is given by:
$$
w_{\perp} = \frac{ m_{s} }{ 2 } \Omega_{cs}^{2} \ \rho_{cs}^{2} \tag{1}
$$
where $m_{s}$ is the mass of species $s$, $\Omega_{cs} = \tfrac{ q_{s} \ B }{ m_{s} }$ is the cyclotron frequency of species $s$, $\rho_{cs} = \tfrac{ m_{s} \ v_{\perp} }{ q_{s} \ B }$ is the [gyroradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius) of species $s$, and $v_{\perp}$ is the perpendicular velocity of the particle with respect to $\mathbf{B}$.

The [curvature drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center) of a particle is given by:
$$
V_{curv} = \frac{ 2 \ w_{\parallel} }{ q_{s} \ B^{2} } \ \left[ \frac{ \mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{R}_{c} }{ R_{c}^{2} } \right] \tag{2}
$$
where $\mathbf{R}_{c}$ is the [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) vector and $R_{c}$ its magnitude, $w_{\parallel} = \tfrac{ 1 }{ 2 } m_{s} \ v_{\parallel}^{2}$ is the parallel kinetic energy, and $v_{\parallel}$ is parallel velocity of the particle with respect to $\mathbf{B}$.  Note that Equation 2 can be rewritten as:
$$
V_{curv} = \frac{ 2 \ w_{\parallel} }{ q_{s} \ B } \ \left[ \frac{ \mathbf{B} \times \nabla B }{ B^{2} } \right] \tag{3}
$$
which means we can combine these into one form called the *gradient curvature drift* given by:
$$
V_{gc} = \frac{ m_{s} }{ 2 \ q_{s} \ B } \left( v_{\perp}^{2} + 2 \ v_{\parallel}^{2} \right) \left[ \frac{ \mathbf{B} \times \nabla B }{ B^{2} } \right] \tag{4}
$$

> I know that the last one is the correct one, but where is the mistake on the first try?

Well, technically the proper version of the one you present should have a term like:
$$
\mathbf{B} \times \left( \mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{B} \right)
$$
where the last term is rank-2 tensor, not the gradient of a scalar.  Then there's an extra term using your field in spherical coordinates.  That is, the result would be something like:
$$
\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{B} = - \hat{r} \frac{ B_{\theta}^{2} }{ r } + \hat{\theta} \frac{ B_{\theta} }{ r } \frac{ \partial \ B_{\theta} }{ \partial \ \theta } \tag{5}
$$
Then the $\mathbf{B}$ crossed into this vector will not be zero.

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about where that extra term from the rank two tensor comes from? I've never used the formula before, so in my head it was as in the question

Comment: @Bidon - It's just a rule from vector calculus with tensors.  You can see the $\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla B$ version at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates.  The full tensor version takes a little bit of tedious algebra but it's not terribly difficult to work out by hand.

Comment: oh the material derivative, thank you!