# Curvature Drift In Plasma Derivation - But Centrifugal Force does not exist in inertial reference frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, plasma-physics, centrifugal-force

In the textbook 'Introduction to Plasma Physics and Controlled Fusion' (F. Chen) the Curvature Drift of a particle in a magnetic field with constant radius of curvature is derived like this:

A particle in the field experiences a **centrifugal** force $\vec{F}_{cf}$, pointing outwards from the center of curvature.

Then, because we know that a force applied to a particle in a magnetic field results in a drift, given by $\vec{v} = \frac{1}{q}\frac{\vec{F}\times\vec{B}}{B^2}$, it follows that the drift due to the curvature of the B field is $\vec{v}_R = \frac{1}{q}\frac{\vec{F}_{cf}\times\vec{B}}{B^2}$.

This argument doesn't seem convincing to me: The equation for the drift of
a particle when experiencing a general force was derived in an inertial reference frame. Now we are substituting the centrifugal force, which only exists in the accelerating reference frame of the particle, for $\vec{F}$ to find the drift.

Why aren't we using the centripetal force to find the drift, and getting a drift velocity in the opposite direction instead as a result?

Comment: There is no such thing as "centripetal force."  It's a type of acceleration that has been given a label, but the actual forces responsible for the acceleration are the usual well known ones (e.g., tension of a rope for a swing).  As an aside, I wouldn't use Chen to understand this stuff as he oversimplifies things in rather confusing ways (such as this example).  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/556682/59023 and references therein.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks. I frequently see Chen recommended as a book for graduate level plasma physics. What would be a more comprehensive alternative?

Comment: _Introduction to Plasma Physics: With Space, Laboratory and Astrophysical Applications_ by Gurnett and Bhattacharjee is a much better option, in my opinion.  It depends also on what you want to learn.  If you are interested in waves etc., there are other specialty books that are worth a look.